# CREATE table using INFER_SCHEMA except not fully

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

how may I tweak the result of `INFER_SCHEMA` a bit before using it to create a table?
I have the following `CREATE`

```
CREATE or REPLACE TABLE A_TSW_G_SPC_1 USING TEMPLATE (
        SELECT   ARRAY_AGG(OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*)) FROM (
        Select  COLUMN_NAME,'TIMESTAMP_NTZ' as TYPE,NULLABLE,REGEXP_REPLACE(EXPRESSION,'TEXT', 'TIMESTAMP_NTZ') as EXPRESSION,FILENAMES , ORDER_ID
FROM TABLE(INFER_SCHEMA(
            LOCATION => '@CMO_HK_STG_A_TSW_G_SPC',
            FILE_FORMAT => 'DC_PARQUET'
        )  ) where COLUMN_NAME ='__TIMESTAMP'
        union all
Select  * FROM TABLE(INFER_SCHEMA(
            LOCATION => '@CMO_HK_STG_A_TSW_G_SPC',
            FILE_FORMAT => 'DC_PARQUET'
        )  ) where COLUMN_NAME !='__TIMESTAMP'
        ) ORDER BY ORDER_ID
    );
```

What I want to achieve is to change the inferred result of the `__TIMESTAMP` column from `TEXT` to `TIMESTAMP_NTZ` and put all the data types back together and create a table with it.
However, I encounter the error
**000002 (0A000): Unsupported feature 'INFER_SCHEMA function must be used in the TEMPLATE sub-query'.**
as if when I alter the `INFER_SCHEMA` output like this, `TEMPLATE` fails to recognise this sub-query.

Is there a way to use this `TEMPLATE` and `INFER_SCHEMA` combo, yet with the flexibility of adding some tweaks?